# If a weighted HTTP header has duplicate values, with differing weights, how should this be handled?

Tags: http-headers, rfc, content-negotiation

Values of request headers, such as `Accept-Language`, `Accept-Encoding`, etc., have either implicitly or explicitly weighted values (`en; q=0.8` for instance).

In the unlikely event that the parsed value of the complete field value yields ambiguous information, specifically if the ambiguity can be interpreted as either not acceptable (`q=0`) or acceptable because of some non-zero quality value, for example:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip; q=0.8, gzip; q=0
```

should this be interpreted as:

1. not acceptable;
2. acceptable;
3. header is invalid;

or some other option, perhaps?

In [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the general [section 5.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.1) on quality values

> The weight is normalized to a real number in the range 0 through 1,
> where 0.001 is the least preferred and 1 is the most preferred; a
> value of 0 means "not acceptable".  If no "q" parameter is present,
> the default weight is 1.

and the `Accept-Encoding`-specific [section 5.3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.4), subsection 3 and 4

> 3. If the representation's content-coding is one of the
>    content-codings listed in the Accept-Encoding field, then it is
>    acceptable unless it is accompanied by a qvalue of 0.  (As
>    defined in Section 5.3.1, a qvalue of 0 means "not acceptable".)
> 4. If multiple content-codings are acceptable, then the acceptable
>    content-coding with the highest non-zero qvalue is preferred.

clearly say `q=0` means "not acceptable" and that the highest non-zero qvalue is preferred, but they don't appear to discuss any possible ambiguity; probably because it is such an unlikely event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 3. If the representation's content-coding is one of the
>         content-codings listed in the Accept-Encoding field, then it is
>         acceptable unless it is accompanied by a qvalue of 0.  (As
>         defined in Section 5.3.1, a qvalue of 0 means "not acceptable".)
> 4. If multiple content-codings are acceptable, then the acceptable
>         content-coding with the highest non-zero qvalue is preferred.

The header `Accept-Encoding: gzip; q=0.8, gzip; q=0` has a single content-coding `gzip` which is repeated with different qvalues.

- First, it is accompanied by the qvalue `0.8` which is "acceptable"
- Second, it is accompanied by the qvalue `0` which is "not-acceptable".

As I read the quoted rules:

1. Check to see if a content-coding is accompanied by a qvalue of zero; if so, it is "not acceptable";
2. Otherwise, take the maximum qvalue weight of all the duplicates.

So my interpretation would be that the two lines below are equivalent:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, gzip;q=0.001, compress;q=0.1, compress;q=0, *;q=0.2, *;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1, compress;q=0, *;q=0.2
```

and for your example, the following two lines are the same:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip; q=0.8, gzip; q=0
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=0
```

Comment: This is a compelling argument, but I think there are two problems:

- It relies on changing the definition of "content-coding" between the two steps. In the first, “the” content-coding is said to have “a” quality value. In the second, for this interpretation, we must consider content coding to refer not to a unique token but rather to individual occurrences of the token.

- It applies only to accept-encoding. None of the other negotiation headers have rules that permit this interpretation.

I’m pretty sure it’s just unspecified behavior, though this is a good choice for how to handle it.